# change currentTarget of event for event delegation

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to add some delegate event on a website and I fail to have a function that match traditionnal listener callback signature (`function( event ) {}`), and to get current listenning element i need to pass another param to function.

Here what i manage to achieve :

```js
const delegate = function( element, events, target, callback ) {
    events.split( " " ).forEach( event => element.addEventListener( event, function( e ) {
        let initiator;
        if ( e.target && ( initiator = e.target.closest( target ) ) ) {
            callback( e, initiator );
        }
    } ) );
};

let count = 0;

delegate( document, "click", ".js-test-delegate", function( event, elem ) {
  elem.innerHTML = `you click on this container ${++count} time(s)`;
} );


const div = document.createElement("div")
div.classList.add( "js-test-delegate" );

document.querySelector( ".container" ) .appendChild( div );
```

```css
.container{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgba(256,0,0,.2);
}

.js-test-delegate{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background: rgba(0,256,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Is there a way to pass that `elem` element within the event, to make him replace `currentTarget` property to have an easier behavior ?

I try modifing  `Event` but property like `currentTarget` are read only or cloning event `event = new Event( "click", e)` but `target` and `currentTarget` are not set at this moment.

And of course this need to be in vanilla js.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use `.call()` to invoke the callback with the element reference as the value of `this`:

```
    if ( e.target && ( initiator = e.target.closest( target ) ) ) {
        callback.call(initiator, e);
    }
```

In the callback, `this` will refer to the "initiator" and you won't need another parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the wanted element to the event object as a custom property, like this:

```
const delegate = function( element, events, target, callback ) {
    events.split(" ").forEach(event => element.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
       let initiator = e.target.closest(target);
       if (e.target && initiator) {
           e.initiator= initiator;
           callback(e);
           // If you want also to bind this to the initiator, call:
           // callback.call(initiator, e);
       }
    }));
};
```

Now you can read the custom property from `event` object:

```
delegate(document, 'click', '.js-test-delegate'", function(e) {
  e.initiator.innerHTML = `you click on this container ${++count} time(s)`;
});
```

Circumventing the read-only protection on the properties in the `event` object is possible, but not a trivial task. You would need to create a new object, and add all the properties to it, and additionally bind `this` value of all the methods to the original event. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yLh087dt/1/) doing this, but it's not much tested, and may fail with some specific events.